# Count the length of each word in a string using charAt, IndexOf

Tags: java

I am looking for a way to create a method with the initial state in while loop, which will count the length of each word in a string using charAt, IndexOf.
I want the output to be something along the lines of:

> hello world how are you

```
There are 0 words of length 0 
There are 0 words of length 1 
There are 0 words of length 2 
There are 3 words of length 3 
There are 0 words of length 4 
There are 2 words of length 5
```

Comment: Would you be open to using `String.length()`?

Comment: You can split the string, get the length of the individual pieces, and store that into a hash map.  Can you use that or do you have a limitation placed on you not to do that?

Comment: yes id be open to using String.length() and not been set a limitation but haven't worked with hash maps yet not been doing java long.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count(String s, int len){
            int result=0;
            StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(s,"[ ,;]");
            while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
                if(st.nextToken().length()==len){
                    result++;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

 void loopMethod(){
            String s="Hello world how are you";
            for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){
                System.out.println("There are "+count(s,i)+" words of lenghth "+i);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void run(){
            String s="Hello world how are you";
            Map<Integer, Integer> result=new TreeMap<>();

            StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(s,"[ ,;]");//[ ,;]-regex
                while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
                    int lenght=st.nextToken().length();
                    if(!result.containsKey(lenght)){
                        result.put(lenght, 1);
                }
                    else{
                        result.put(lenght, result.get(lenght)+1);
                    }


        }       /*//display only if you have 1 or more words of that length
                for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e:result.entrySet()){ 
                    System.out.println("There are "+e.getValue()+" words of length "+e.getKey());
                }
}
```

This is a more complicated variant, created using TreeMap(a HashMap which order the keys). Also, you can parse the String using Pattern and Matcher classes. They are more efficient.